# XML - Attribute to Element - MS Access

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, element

I'm new to XML/XSLT and I'm learning to import XML to Access database. I'm facing issues while importing the below structure. The Input XML is as below (dummy data)

```
<Root>
<School Name = "ABC" Address = "XYZ"/>

<Students>

<Student ID = "123" Name = "John" Bdate = "1/1/2000">
<StudentData Address = "555 street" City = "Dummy" State = "FL"/>
</Student>

<Student ID = "234" Name = "Jane" Bdate = "1/2/2000">
<StudentData Address = "665 street" City = "Dummy" State = "FL"/>
</Student>

<Student ID = "456" Name = "Joshua" Bdate = "1/3/2000">
<StudentData Address = "775 street" City = "Dummy" State = "FL"/>
</Student>

</Students>
</Root>
```

I want the output XML in this format so that when I load it to Access database I can have all the Student and Studentdata details in a single table.

```
<Root>
<School Name = "ABC" Address = "XYZ"/>
<Students>
<Student>
<ID>"123"</ID>
<Name>"John"</Name>
<Bdate>"1/1/2000"</Bdate>
<Address>"555 street"</Address>
<City>"Dummy"</City>
<State>"FL"</State>
</Student>

<Student>
<ID>"123"</ID>
<Name>"John"</Name>
<Bdate>"1/1/2000"</Bdate>
<Address>"555 street"</Address>
<City>"Dummy"</City>
<State>"FL"</State>
</Student>

<Student>
<ID>"123"</ID>
<Name>"John"</Name>
<Bdate>"1/1/2000"</Bdate>
<Address>"555 street"</Address>
<City>"Dummy"</City>
<State>"FL"</State>
</Student>

</Students>
</Root>
```

I tried the using the below for xsl transformation to convert attribute to elements but it does not give me the desired result. I get student details in one table and studentdata in another.
I need both to be in the same table in access database

```
<xsl:template match="*"
 <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:element name ="{name()}">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The code you show as the output you want is not a well-formed XML document. Find out **exactly** what the result should look like in order to import correctly. Then ask how to get it using XSLT.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I'm sorry, I did not realize it. I have updated my post to correct the output XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Students>
        <xsl:for-each select="Students/Student">
            <Student>
                <xsl:for-each select="@* | StudentData/@*">
                    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Student>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Students>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Students>
  <Student>
    <ID>123</ID>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Bdate>1/1/2000</Bdate>
    <Address>555 street</Address>
    <City>Dummy</City>
    <State>FL</State>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <ID>234</ID>
    <Name>Jane</Name>
    <Bdate>1/2/2000</Bdate>
    <Address>665 street</Address>
    <City>Dummy</City>
    <State>FL</State>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <ID>456</ID>
    <Name>Joshua</Name>
    <Bdate>1/3/2000</Bdate>
    <Address>775 street</Address>
    <City>Dummy</City>
    <State>FL</State>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is perfect. I now understand that I have to create 2 loops to get to the format I need.